# System.TypeInitializationException: 'The type initializer for 'Caliburn.Micro.Message' threw an exception.'

Tags: caliburn.micro

System.TypeInitializationException: 'The type initializer for 'Caliburn.Micro.Message' threw an exception.'

Inner Exception 1:
FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Windows.Interactivity, Version=4.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'. The system cannot find the file specified.

System.TypeInitializationException: 'The type initializer for 'Caliburn.Micro.Message' threw an exception.'

Inner Exception 1:
FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Windows.Interactivity, Version=4.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'. The system cannot find the file specified.